# GPO error 0x80070547 with Server 2008 R2 and XP SP3, but not Win7

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-xp, group-policy

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server managing XP SP3 and Windows 7 SP1 clients.

There are no issues with the Windows 7 clients.

However, on the Windows XP clients, I get errors for power options, scheduled tasks, and shortcuts policies in the "Computer configuration" section of group policy. The Client Side Extensions for XP have long since been installed.

Below I have included what appears in the event viewer, and what appears in the computer.log trace file on the client. However--I don't know what to do next, as I can't seem to find any information on the error code.

Here's what appears in the event viewer:

```
event ID: 8194
source: group policy power options
The client-side extension could not apply computer policy settings for 'default - power settings {A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}' because it failed with error code '0x80070547 Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.' See trace file for more details.

event ID: 8194
source: group policy shortcuts
The client-side extension could not apply computer policy settings for 'default - desktop {3F5EF3E3-5073-4305-B86E-8F2ACED7206C}' because it failed with error code '0x80070547 Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.' See trace file for more details.

event ID: 8194
source: group policy registry
The client-side extension could not apply computer policy settings for 'default - GP settings {E49DA0F1-C166-4516-9045-94858969AAA5}' because it failed with error code '0x80070547 Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.' See trace file for more details.

event ID: 8194
source: group policy scheduled tasks
The client-side extension could not apply computer policy settings for 'default - scheduled tasks (XP) {E9E1C766-5C4A-41F7-B32C-9FFA227E7641}' because it failed with error code '0x80070547 Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.' See trace file for more details.
```

I enabled tracing, and here's the section for scheduled tasks:

```
2013-04-16 10:00:54.993 [pid=0x28c,tid=0xf4] Entering ProcessGroupPolicyExPowerOptions()
2013-04-16 10:00:54.993 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Group Policy\{E62688F0-25FD-4c90-BFF5-F508B9D2E31F}
2013-04-16 10:00:54.993 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] BackgroundPriorityLevel ( 0 )
2013-04-16 10:00:54.993 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] DisableRSoP ( 0 )
2013-04-16 10:00:54.993 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] LogLevel ( 3 )
2013-04-16 10:00:54.993 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Command subsystem initialized. [SUCCEEDED(S_FALSE)]
2013-04-16 10:00:54.993 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Client context subsystem initialized.
2013-04-16 10:00:54.993 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Configuration subsystem initialized.
2013-04-16 10:00:54.993 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Licensing subsystem initialized.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] User information initialized.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %ComSpec% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %Path% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %windir% = "C:\WINDOWS"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %FP_NO_HOST_CHECK% = "NO"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %OS% = "Windows_NT"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% = "x86"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PROCESSOR_LEVEL% = "15"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER% = "x86 Family 15 Model 3 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PROCESSOR_REVISION% = "0304"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% = "1"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PATHEXT% = ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %TEMP% = "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %TMP% = "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %TEMP% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Local Settings\Temp"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.008 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %TMP% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Local Settings\Temp"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %ComSpec% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %Path% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %windir% = "C:\WINDOWS"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %FP_NO_HOST_CHECK% = "NO"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %OS% = "Windows_NT"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% = "x86"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PROCESSOR_LEVEL% = "15"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER% = "x86 Family 15 Model 3 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PROCESSOR_REVISION% = "0304"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% = "1"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %PATHEXT% = ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %TEMP% = "C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Local Settings\Temp"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %TMP% = "C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Local Settings\Temp"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %ALLUSERSPROFILE% = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %CommonProgramFiles% = "C:\Program Files\Common Files"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %COMPUTERNAME% = "YG-SAR-4"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %ProgramFiles% = "C:\Program Files"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %SystemDrive% = "C:"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %SystemRoot% = "C:\WINDOWS"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %USERDNSDOMAIN% = "domain.local"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %USERDOMAIN% = "DOMAIN"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %USERNAME% = "YG-SAR-4$"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %USERPROFILE% = "C:\Documents and Settings\Default User"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %LogonUser% = ""
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %LogonDomain% = ""
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %LogonUserSid% = "S-1-5-21-1615453892-3105553421-2752998754-1121"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %BinaryUserSid% = "00000461A4176D62B91AFC0D6049DEC4000000150500000000000501"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %LdapUserSid% = "\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\C4\DE\49\60\0D\FC\1A\B9\62\6D\17\A4\61\04\00\00"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %ReversedUserSid% = "010500000000000515000000C4DE49600DFC1AB9626D17A461040000"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %BinaryComputerSid% = "00000461A4176D62B91AFC0D6049DEC4000000150500000000000501"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %ReversedComputerSid% = "010500000000000515000000C4DE49600DFC1AB9626D17A461040000"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %LdapComputerSid% = "\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\C4\DE\49\60\0D\FC\1A\B9\62\6D\17\A4\61\04\00\00"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %OsVersion% = "Windows XP"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %LocalTimeEx% = "2013-04-16 10:00:55.008"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %LocalTime% = "2013-04-16 10:00:55"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %DateTimeEx% = "2013-04-16 14:00:55.008"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %DateTime% = "2013-04-16 14:00:55"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %MacAddress% = "00-11-11-6a-aa-75"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %TempDir% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Local Settings\Temp"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %WindowsDir% = "C:\WINDOWS"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %SystemDir% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %DomainName% = "DOMAIN"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %ProgramFilesDir% = "C:\Program Files"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %AppDataDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Application Data"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %DesktopDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Desktop"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %StartMenuDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Start Menu"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %ProgramsDir% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Start Menu\Programs"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %StartUpDir% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %FavoritesDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Favorites"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %SendToDir% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\SendTo"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %RecentDocumentsDir% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Recent"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %NetPlacesDir% = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\NetHood"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %CommonAppdataDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %CommonDesktopDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %CommonStartMenuDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %CommonProgramsDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %CommonStartUpDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %CommonFavoritesDir% = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Favorites"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %CurrentProcessId% = "652"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %CurrentThreadId% = "1684"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %GroupPolicyVersion% = "5.2.3790.4568"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %TraceFile% = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\GroupPolicy\Preference\Trace\Computer.log"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %LastError% = "0x00000000"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %LastErrorText% = "The operation completed successfully."
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variables subsystem initialized.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] ----- Parameters
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] CSE GUID : {E62688F0-25FD-4c90-BFF5-F508B9D2E31F}
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Flags : ( X ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_MACHINE - Apply machine policy rather than user policy
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]         (   ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_BACKGROUND - Background refresh of policy (ok to do slow stuff)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]         (   ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_SLOWLINK - Policy is being applied across a slow link
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]         (   ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_VERBOSE - Verbose output to the eventlog
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]         ( X ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_NOCHANGES - No changes were detected to the Group Policy Objects
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]         (   ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_LINKTRANSITION - A change in link speed was detected between previous policy application and current policy application
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]         (   ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_LOGRSOP_TRANSITION - A change in RSoP logging was detected between the application of the previous policy and the application of the current policy.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]         (   ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_FORCED_REFRESH - Forced Refresh is being applied. redo policies.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]         (   ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_SAFEMODE_BOOT - windows safe mode boot flag
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]         (   ) GPO_INFO_FLAG_ASYNC_FOREGROUND - Asynchronous foreground refresh of policy
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Token (computer or user SID): S-1-5-18
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Abort Flag : Yes (0x76a613c8)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] HKey Root : Yes (0x80000002)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Deleted GPO List : No
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Changed GPO List : Yes
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Asynchronous Processing : Yes
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Status Callback : Yes (0x769d2c56)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] WMI namespace : No (0x00000000)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] RSoP Status : Yes (0x0119f930)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Planning Mode Site : (none)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Computer Target : No (0x00000000)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] User Target : No (0x00000000)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.181 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Calculated session relevance.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed CSE pre-processing.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Calculated list relevance. [SUCCEEDED(S_FALSE)]
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Deleted GPO list is not relevant to the CSE.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Calculated list relevance.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Planning mode not detected.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Processing changed list.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Processing computer policy.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Got WMI namespace for logging mode.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed get GPO list.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Initialized internal RSoP storage.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed GPO list pre-processing.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] ----- Changed - 0
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Options : (   ) GPO_FLAG_DISABLE - This GPO is disabled.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]           (   ) GPO_FLAG_FORCE - Do not override the settings in this GPO with settings in a subsequent GPO.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Options (raw) : 0x00000000
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Version : 2097184 (0x00200020)
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] GPC : LDAP://CN=Machine,cn={A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=DOMAIN,DC=local
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] GPT : \\domain.local\SysVol\domain.local\Policies\{A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}\Machine
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] GPO Display Name : default - power settings
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] GPO Name : {A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] GPO Link : (   ) GPLinkUnknown - No link information is available.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]            (   ) GPLinkMachine - The GPO is linked to a computer (local or remote).
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]            (   ) GPLinkSite - The GPO is linked to a site.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]            ( X ) GPLinkDomain - The GPO is linked to a domain.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]            (   ) GPLinkOrganizationalUnit - The GPO is linked to an organizational unit.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694]            (   ) GP Link Error
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] lParam : 0x00000000
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Prev GPO : No
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Next GPO : No
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Extensions : [{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}{9AD2BAFE-63B4-4883-A08C-C3C6196BCAFD}][{35378EAC-683F-11D2-A89A-00C04FBBCFA2}{D02B1F72-3407-48AE-BA88-E8213C6761F1}][{E62688F0-25FD-4C90-BFF5-F508B9D2E31F}{9AD2BAFE-63B4-4883-A08C-C3C6196BCAFD}]
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] lParam2 : 0x00ea71d4
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Link : LDAP://DC=DOMAIN,DC=local
2013-04-16 10:00:55.197 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %GPHPATH% = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Group Policy\History\{A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}\Machine"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed get GPH path.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] GPH : C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Group Policy\History\{A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}\Machine\Preferences\PowerOptions\PowerOptions.xml
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed set extensions.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed get GPO is relevant.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Variable %GPTPATH% = "\\domain.local\SysVol\domain.local\Policies\{A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}\Machine"
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed get GPT path.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] GPT : \\domain.local\SysVol\domain.local\Policies\{A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}\Machine\Preferences\PowerOptions\PowerOptions.xml
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed RSoP init.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed get next GPO.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed check GPO license usage.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed GPO pre-processing.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Started removing policy.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.228 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] GPH data file : C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Group Policy\History\{A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}\Machine\Preferences\PowerOptions\PowerOptions.xml
2013-04-16 10:00:55.244 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Read GPH data file.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.244 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed parse of GPH XML.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.244 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed get tree root.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Deleted GPH data file.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Started package execution.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Set package timestamp variable (2013-04-16 14:00:55).
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Starting class <PowerOptions>.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Handle Children.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] {46D0DCC4-FC14-48fb-829B-854868C7DC16}
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Starting class <GlobalPowerOptions> - Power Options (Windows XP).
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Policy is not flagged for removal.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed class <GlobalPowerOptions> - Power Options (Windows XP).
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] {DE828AFA-7E71-480e-8081-5447CBE87754}
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Starting class <PowerScheme> - Home/Office Desk.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Policy is not flagged for removal.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed class <PowerScheme> - Home/Office Desk.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed class <PowerOptions>.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed package execution.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed execution of removal package.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed remove GPH.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Started applying policy.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.291 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] GPE data file : \\domain.local\SysVol\domain.local\Policies\{A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}\Machine\Preferences\PowerOptions\PowerOptions.xml
2013-04-16 10:00:55.573 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Failed to open file. [ hr = 0x80070547 "Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied." ]
2013-04-16 10:00:55.573 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Error reading GPE XML data file. [ hr = 0x80070547 "Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied." ]
2013-04-16 10:00:55.573 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed loading of package. [ hr = 0x80070547 "Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied." ]
2013-04-16 10:00:55.573 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] EVENT : The client-side extension could not apply computer policy settings for 'default - power settings {A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}' because it failed with error code '0x80070547 Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.'%100790275
2013-04-16 10:00:55.573 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] Completed apply GPO. [ hr = 0x80070547 "Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied." ]
2013-04-16 10:00:55.573 [pid=0x28c,tid=0x694] User impersonation uninitialized.
2013-04-16 10:00:55.714 [pid=0x28c,tid=0xf4] Leaving ProcessGroupPolicyExPowerOptions() returned 0x80070547
2013-04-16 10:00:55.714 [pid=0x28c,tid=0xf4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up renaming the scheduled tasks and adding a permit incoming file sharing rule from the server's IP.

*computer configuration/policies/windows settings/windows firewall with advanced security/inbound rules*

That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: So for clarification, did this truly only effect certain OS's? Seems like your fix would have applied to all. And what did you rename? The GPO? The XML file?

Comment: There's two different sections in GP for firewall rules. The ones under `computer configuration\administrative templates\network\network connections\windows firewall\domain profile` were already in place, which seemed to be recognized by Win7, but not XP. As for renaming, I renamed the scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer is unable to access the Power Options group policy preference configuration file (PowerOptions.xml) on the DC. The file path that is failing in the tracing log is `\\domain.local\SysVol\domain.local\Policies\{A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}\Machine\Preferences\PowerOptions\PowerOptions.xml`. You may have a permissions or replication issue. To rule out a replication issue, ensure that file exists in that location on each DC. You should also take a look at the NTFS permissions on PowerOptions.xml. `Authenticated Users` should have `Read & execute` on that file. Specifically, the computer account needs to be able to access read the file. To test, try this as a user who is a member of the local Administrators group:

1. Run `psexec -s -i -d cmd`
2. In the new command window, run the following: `type \\domain.local\SysVol\domain.local\Policies\{A5C7F7E2-EFEF-4F97-B3B1-8AD8B52CC9E9}\Machine\Preferences\PowerOptions\PowerOptions.xml`
3. If the XML file's permissions are correct, you should see the contents of the file.